# Проблема с поиском элемента в списке

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Существует шаблон списка:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class List {
private:
struct Element {
    T l_data;
    Element *l_next;
};

Element *pHead{};     // указатель на первый элемент списка
Element *pPrev{};     // указатель на последний элемент списка
int countElem;      // количество элементов в списке

public:
List() {
    pHead = nullptr;
    countElem = 0;
}

~List() {
    while (pHead != NULL) {
        Element *pTemp = pHead;
        pHead = pHead->l_next;
        delete pTemp;
    }
}

void addToList(T data) {

    Element *temp;
    temp = new Element;

    if (pHead == NULL)
        pHead = temp;
    else
        pPrev->l_next = temp;

    temp->l_data = data;
    temp->l_next = NULL;
    pPrev = temp;
    ++countElem;
}

void printList() {
    Element *pTemp = pHead;

    while (pTemp != NULL) {
        std::cout << pTemp->l_data << " ";
        pTemp = pTemp->l_next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "Количество: " << countElem << std::endl;
}

  /*  T & findElement(T &aim) {
    Element *pTemp = pHead;


    while (pTemp != nullptr) {
        if (pTemp->l_data == aim){

        }
        else
            pTemp = pTemp->l_next;
    }
}*/

};
```

И существует класс описывающий "сущность" автобуса:

```
 #include <cstring>

 class Bus {

 public:
int b_numRoute;
int b_numBus;
char *b_Name;

Bus() : b_numRoute(0),
        b_numBus(0),
        b_Name(nullptr) {}

Bus(int numRoute, int numBus, const char *Name) {
    b_numBus = numBus;
    b_numRoute = numRoute;
    b_Name = new char[strlen(Name)];
    strcpy(b_Name, Name);
}

~Bus() { delete[]b_Name; }

friend const bool operator == (Bus &bus1, Bus &bus2) { return      bus2.b_numBus == bus1.b_numBus; }

friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &s, Bus &bus) {
    s << "Номер маршрута: " << bus.b_numRoute << std::endl << "Номер   автобуса: " << bus.b_numBus << std::endl;

    /*s << "Имя водителя: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(bus.b_Name); i++)
        s << bus.b_Name[i];*/

    s << std::endl << std::endl;

    return s;
}

};
```

Вопрос вот в чем: Мне нужно создать два списка, затем по номеру автобуса находить элемент в одном списке, и добавлять его в другой. Пробовал переопределить равенство в классе Bus и написать обычный шаблонный поиск в шаблоне List. Но в силу неопытность не выходит, прошу помочь советом, как лучше реализовать подобную вещь. Был бы рад примерам. Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что значит "не выходит"?

Comment: Кажется все очевидным: итерироваться по листу, пока не встретится элемент с искомыми данными. Когда встретили - из одного списка удаляем, в другой - добавляем.

Comment: не так просто поиск элемента в списке осуществляется за счет сравнение data c aim, но мне не нужно сравнивать два объекта класса Bus, а необходима сравнивать лишь одно поле из класса Bus

Comment: @Виктор, попробуйте поступить так же как авторы stl - передавайте в функцию поиска предикат. А вообще все уже давно [написано](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/?kw=find_if). Можете ради спортивного интереса написать для вашего списка итераторы и использовать для поиска стандартный алгоритм. Более того это позволит подружить ваш `List` сразу со всеми алгоритмами из стандартной библиотеки

Comment: За вот это `b_Name = new char[strlen(Name)]; strcpy(b_Name, Name);` маленьким программистам копчик массируют :) - а место для завершающего нулевого символа?

Comment: @harry вы правы, спасибо большое за указание:)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Спасибо большое за совет, буду пробовать

Comment: для чего так много структурного программирования? Можно намного проще если пользоваться возможностьми С++.